# How to pass a list of sheets to a VB Sheets.Select

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to select specific sheets in an workbook. I have a formula that calculates the specific sheets that need to be printed and then creates a quoted comma delimited list i.e. `"Page 1", "Page 5", "Page 18"`

Now I'm trying to pass this to a select to have it exported to PDF using the following code:

```
Sub Print_PDF()

Dim FName As String
Dim Print_Sheets As String

FName = Worksheets("ControlSheet").Cells(5, "B").Value
Print_Sheets = Worksheets("ControlSheet").Cells(56, "G").Value

Sheets(Array(Print_Sheets)).Select
Sheets("Page 1").Activate

Save_Out = "C:\Temp\" + FName + ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Save_Out, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Sheets("Page 1").Select
End Sub
```

However, `Print_Sheets` is passed with an extra set of quotes, i.e`""Page 1", "Page 5", "Page 18""`

How do I remove the extra quotes or is there a better way to pass my list of Sheets to the Sheets.Select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off moving the worksheet names to a pre-defined string array after you physically remove the double quotes like this:

```
'Define a string array for the list of worksheets
Dim arrSheets() As String

...
...

Print_Sheets = Worksheets("ControlSheet").Cells(16, "G").Value

'Remove the double quotes from the delimited list of worksheets
Print_Sheets = Replace(Print_Sheets, """", "")

'Break the worksheet names out into a string array
arrSheets =  Split(Print_Sheets, ",")

'Select the worksheets using the array
Sheets(arrSheets).Select

...
...
```

Comment: That generates an error on Sheets(arrSheets).Select line

Comment: Works ok for me. What is the specific error? Have you put a breakpoint on that instruction to examine the contents of `arrSheets` ?  Are you sure all of those worksheets exist?

Comment: Sheets are comma and space delimited `, `, so the method above was keeping the space in the sheet names, so although they looked correct they didn't exist.

Comment: I changed my Sheet list to not include the spaces/quotes and didn't use the Replace line.